# Google Chome - Sidebar looks broken ONLY on some computers

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, sidebar

I currently have a WordPress theme online and appears to work fine but one of my clients noted that the blog page layout is broken in Google Chrome. The sidebar appears right underneath the page content. So I checked his website and my demo and it does indeed look broken. So I have spoken to another programmer and he says it's not broken and he uses the latest version of Chrome too. I have never encountered such an issue, it works for some but not for others.

EDIT: The issue has been fixed with thanks to Joseph Erickson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it has to do with the width of the `#sidebar`. If you shrink it just a little bit, it'll fit properly.

*Why* is this happening? Who knows. These little pixel shifts with floats can be hard to track down. I would recommend not trying to fit everything so snug together and allow some wiggle room when putting two fixed-width floating elements inside the same element.